# How to get an Android phones's IMEI and color via USB

Tags: android, usb, imei

I am planning to write an application for my job. I just need to get IMEI numbers of Android devices when they are connected to my PC. It would be great if it shows the color of the device together. Because I want to recongnize each phones when pluging many at once.

With these IMEI numbers, I am going to print out labels for inventory managing. Now there are many phones comming to my office everyday. I open back covers and write down manually. Later on, I put the data into excel. I think this is a wasting of my much time.

I do not know where I need to start to write this application. I do not know if this is possible or not. Any comments will be welcome. Anyone have tried this kind of job? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an ADB on your PC
Turn on USB Debugging on your Android Devices
Connect it to PC via usb cable
Use Terminal to adb folder and type

```
adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
```

It can show you IMEI
But about the color, i think it's not possible right now

Answer (score 0):

My script can extract all IMEI numbers and device colors along with a lot of other informations.

It is here: https://github.com/micro5k/microg-unofficial-installer/blob/main/utils/device-info.sh

Note: The device color info will likely be present on just Huawei / Xiaomi devices.